# Google Classroom, can I select 'UnSubmit' to return assignment to the student?

Tags: javascript, add-on, google-classroom

Students submit work that is not complete and they need to finish the assignment before it's graded.  In my add-on, is there code available to change the status from Teacher ownership back to the student so it shows up in Classroom to-do list?  Right now the student needs to select the 'UnSubmit' button, but I would like to do that automatically from my add-on.

I've changed the ownership onto the student,but this action does not change the status with Google Classroom.  Classroom still sees the assignment as "Submitted".